# Why doesn't this piece of code throw an error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebug, web-inspector

It took me a while to find this problem in my code when it stopped working.

```
console.log('before var');
var lastReview = ''
    newReview;
console.log('after var');
```

There is no comma after `lastReview = ''` which I believe is a syntax error, however both Chrome inspector and Firebug report nothing in the console. The following code `console.log` simply is never executed.

Chrome actually reports the error if you run the snippet directly in the console... but not when the actual page runs. Firefox does not report an error in any case.

Why don't the dev tools report these kinds of simple problems?

Comment: http://www.jshint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (syntax) error - this code is valid javascript. According to [the rules](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9.1), JS inserts a semicolon:

```
console.log('before var');
var lastReview = ''; <-- here
    newReview;
console.log('after var');
```

so that `newReview;` becomes a valid, albeit nonsensical, statement.

Although there's no syntax error, this code still throws a runtime error due to undefined variable (assuming `newReview` wasn't declared before).

Comment: OK I suppose my revised question is then, why is the runtime error not reported in the console? It simply silently stops running.

Comment: @MichaelButler: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/cjRBB/) - I see an error message in the console.

Comment: @MichaelButler It works for me too (in both Web Inspector and Firebug). What is your Firebug version? Do you have some Firebug Extensions installed?

Answer (score 1):

Because semi-colons are automatically inserted anyway if missing - so there is no syntax error in the code.

Read more about this here in the [Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.1) section of the ECMAScript Language Specification.

In your example, this:

```
var lastReview = ''
```

becomes:

```
var lastReview = '';
```